# Replace text next to static text google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to replace the text in a google doc. At the moment I have place markers as follows

```
Invoice ##invoiceNumber##
```

I replace the invoice number with

```
body.replaceText('##invoiceNumber##',invoiceNumber);
```

Which is fine but I can only run the script once as obviously `##invoiceNumber##` is no longer in the document. I was thinking I could replace the text after `Invoice` as this will stay the same, `appendParagraph` looks like it might to the trick but I can't figure it out. I think something like `body.appendParagraph("Invoice")` would select the area? Not sure how to append to this after that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this I think:

```
body.replaceText('InvoiceNumber \\w{1,9} ','InvoiceNumber ' + invoicenumber);
```

I don't know how big your invoice numbers are but that will except from 1 to 9 word characters preceeded by a space and followed by a space.  That  pattern might have to be modified depending upon your textual needs.

Word Characters `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

If your invoice numbers are unique enough perhaps you could just replace them.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String))

[Regular Expression Syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)

Note: the regex pattern is passed as a string rather than a regular expression